# Error With Fabulous Python Module: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

Tags: python, module

I get this error when I am trying to use the fabulous module in python and I don't know how to fix it.
-Note: I am on windows

-code-

```
from fabulous import text
print(text.Text("Main Menu", shadow=True))
```

-error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from fabulous import text
  File "C:\Users\impec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fabulous\text.py", line 55, in <module>
    from fabulous import utils, image, grapefruit
  File "C:\Users\impec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fabulous\utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow/issues/10

The module you are using isn't supported on windows.

You could use docker to run it and that is discussed more in depth in the Github issue I linked.

Another possibility would be to run it in the WSL(2). [Source](https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow/issues/60)